# How to encrypt values passed in url at one place

Tags: php, encryption, url-rewriting

I don't know if it is possible or not but any help would be appreciated.

Following is the directory structure of my project (it's in the core php)

```
application/
application/sub_application_1
application/sub_application_2
application/sub_application_3
..
application/sub_application_n
```

So, there are many sub applications which has multiples php files in it and in those files various url redirection code is written, with url parameters are simply encoded using `base64_encode()`. Also in all the files one unique config file is included.

Now, I want to use my own function to encode/encrypt all the url parameters through out the entire application. So instead of going in each file and adding my own function for encoding and decoding, can I write some code in single file which is included in all the files (In my case the config file), which will take care of all the url parameters encoding and decoding in the entire application?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

Let's say I have one php file in the `application/sub_application_1/index.php` and in that file one hyper link is written which redirect the page to `application/sub_application_1/product_details.php`.

Following is the current code

`<a href="./product_details.php?product_id=<?php echo base64_encode($_product_id); ?>"> View Product </a>`

So, I want to mount my encryption function on every hyper link, like

`<a href="./product_details.php?product_id=<?php echo my_encryption(base64_encode($_product_id)); ?>"> View Product </a>`

So, there is a tedious way of going in each directory and each file and add my function on each url parameter for encryption and similarly to that particular file for decryption.

Any other way, where writing some code in single file which will also work like this?

Comment: Sounds possible. But we can't really help unless we see some example code (i.e. what you're trying to decrypt) and anything you've tried. If you could update your question with these that would help get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added example for reference.

Comment: In the end you'll have to do exactly that in some form or another. You'll have to call some specific function which will create the URL. You can write that function to be more intelligent/do more of the work to reduce the code needed to write each time for each URL, but you can't get around explicitly calling that function for each URL you want to generate. There's no global "Imma create a URL now" hook that you can magically hook into without writing any code.

Comment: Thanks, now I will stop looking for that magical hook :D

Comment: Can I offer a better suggestion? [**Don't encrypt URL parameters.**](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably going to be a certain amount of manual work here, but some ideas to try:

---

## Using the command line

You could use the command line to replace the existing links with the format you want. If all your `base64_encode()` links are going to be wrapped in `my_encryption()` then I suggest also moving the `base64_encode()` call to your function. Then, you can do a search and replace on the links in question to replace with your own. Something like this:

```
find application/*/*.php -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/base64_encode/my_encrpytion/g"
```

I *strongly* suggest making a backup of your files before running this as it's not tested and I don't know much more about your code

---

## Using an editor, like Notepad++

You can essentially do the same as the command line but in an editor, like Notepad++, if you don't have access to or don't want to use the command line. Open all the files in question and then replace contents in all files. Depending on whether you have other `base64_encode()` calls in there would determine whether you can do a straight text replacement or have to use a regex. The regex method, for instance, would look something like this:

[image: notepad++ example]

---

## Further notes

If you want to replace the whole links (i.e. the `product_details.php?product_id` part too, you could move this bit inside the above search/replaces and put that in to you `my_encryption` function. Then after changing the existing files, in the future you could just write:

```
<a href="<?php echo my_encryption('xxx'); ?>">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, It will definitely help me while executing the changes.